# Add something to the driver section inside the package code using \OnlyDescription

Tags: dtx

I would like to be able to add something to the documentation of a package in `dtx` format but using `\OnlyDescription`.

I don't want the Implementation section, but somewhere on the package code I want to add a comment to be written to the documentation.

Neither starting the line with `%<driver>` nor with `%` results in appending this line to the package documentation, I guess because the `driver` section at the beginning of `dtx` file ends with `\end{document}`, so everything after this line is ignored.

There is a solution moving `\end{document}` or `\StopEventually` to a different place?

The purpose is writing TO-DO notes with the package `todo` regarding something to be done in the code, but would be good if all these notes appears in the documentation after the change history, for example. I don't include the code section in the documentation (`\OnlyDescription`). MWE:

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% ...
%<*internalbatchfile>
\begingroup
%</internalbatchfile>
%<*batchfile>
\input docstrip.tex
\nopreamble
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}
%</batchfile>
%<batchfile>\endbatchfile
%<*internalbatchfile>
\endgroup
%</internalbatchfile>
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{test.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{test}[2015/03/28 v1.00 Test package]
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\OnlyDescription
\begin{document}
 \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \CheckSum{0}
% \section{doc begins}
% \StopEventually{}
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\relax
% **Here** I would like to add something to the documentation here between 'package' tags.
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%\Finale
```

Comment: I think we need a MWE: I don't really see what you are after here.

Comment: Just added the MWE.

Comment: What I'm missing here is why you have `\StopEventually{}` before the stuff you want in the doc part: the whole point of `\StopEventually{}` to mark the end of the 'documentation'. You can happily have DocStrip guards before it or even set them up for out-of-order code extraction. Perhaps that's what you need: I can provide a demo :-)

Comment: For example moving `\StopEventually{}` to the end, just before `\Finale`? This way the whole code is written to the pdf documentation... or how?

Comment: You can split the code part: doesn't all have to be in one block, all before or all after `\StopEventually{}`. I'm still not really seeing the issue here! Perhaps pop into chat: this might need a bit of discussion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want. Make sure the two final lines of the `.dtx` are

```
% \Finale
% \starttodo
```

Here is the code

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% Time-stamp: <29-03-2015 22:35:13 CEST>
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235680/4686
%<*internalbatchfile>
\begingroup
%</internalbatchfile>
%<*batchfile>
\input docstrip.tex
\nopreamble
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\generate{\file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}}
%</batchfile>
%<batchfile>\endbatchfile
%<*internalbatchfile>
\endgroup
%</internalbatchfile>
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{testspecial.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{testspecial}[2015/03/28 v1.00 Test package]
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
%\OnlyDescription
\begin{document}
 \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \long\def\stoptodo#1\starttodo {}%
% \long\def\starttodo#1\stoptodo {}%
% \makeatletter
% \def\endorgo #1{\ifx #1\endinput\expandafter\stoptodo
%                  \else #1\expandafter\@gobble\fi}%
% \makeatother
% \CheckSum{0}
% \section{doc begins}
% This is the documentation for this package.
%
% \StopEventually{\endorgo}
%
% \section{implementation begins}
% The code required years of efforts. Finally I found this:
% \starttodo
% IMPORTANT NOTE TO MYSELF! Try to enhance the package with some features.
% \stoptodo
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
\relax
%    \end{macrocode}
% And after a few more years I got that:
% \starttodo
% SECOND IMPORTANT NOTE TO MYSELF: at least try.
% \stoptodo
%    \begin{macrocode}
\endinput
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% \Finale
% \starttodo
```

Here is the result without `\OnlyDescription`:

[image]

and the result with `\OnlyDescription`:

[image]

Comment: I'll try your code! The package urges us and the TeX engine to relax. Isn't a good recommendation? ;-)

Comment: It works, but not always... We can't put the to-do code in any place, for example inside a group `{}`. If we define a command in the package, the to-do note must be written before or after the definition because it can't be placed between the braces!